# Zooming an OpenLayers3 map to cover multiple vector layers

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have an OpenLayers3 map consisting of an OSM Tile layer and one or more Vector layers. I can zoom the map into a single layer using

```
vector.addEventListener("change", function() {
    map.getView().fitExtent(vectorSource.getExtent(), map.getSize());
});
```

and this works. However, if I try to zoom to cover multiple layers using the following in the loop that adds layers

```
vector.addEventListener("change", function () {
    if (bounds == null) {
        bounds = vectorSource.getExtent();
    } else {
        bounds = bounds.extend(vectorSource.getExtent());
    }
    map.getView().fitExtent(bounds, map.getSize());
});
```

with bounds being declared outside the loop, then maps with a single layer continue to work. However, with more than one layer, the code in the else block give the error "undefined is not a function".

According to the documentation [getExtent() returns an extent object](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html#getExtent) and [the extent object has an extend method](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.extent.html#extend), so I'm not sure why this errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering own question as I worked it out. I was using extend wrongly. The correct code is:

```
vector.addEventListener("change", function () {
    if (bounds == null) {
        bounds = vectorSource.getExtent();
    } else {
        bounds = ol.extent.extend(bounds, vectorSource.getExtent());
    }
    map.getView().fitExtent(bounds, map.getSize());
});
```

Comment: You could also initialize `bounds` to `ol.extent.createEmpty()` instead of `null`. This way you wouldn't have to check in the listener whether `bounds` is `null` or not, and always use `ol.extent.extend`.

Comment: fitExtent has been changed to fit since 3.7. With that change this still works!